# AngularJs Slice object in existing array

Tags: angularjs

I want to remove the object if already exists (which means exist in the selected array).

Please check below `Plunker` for More details.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Bfq879sOBWVB5Kb0t6Ae?p=preview

Comment: Please check this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Bfq879sOBWVB5Kb0t6Ae?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can remove element from an array using `splice(index, 1)`:

```
var index = arr.indexOf(element);
if(index > -1)
   arr.splice(index,1);
```

If the array is array of objects then you need to get the index in another way, in Angular you can pass `$filter` in your service or controller and use it like this:

```
var obj = $filter('filter')(arr, {id: fish_id}, true);  
var index = arr.indexOf(obj);
```

Now you have the index you can continue using the first code I wrote using `splice`.